# How to load an image from cli stdout into buffer and insert to canvas

Tags: javascript, node.js, buffer, node-canvas

I need to load an image generated from a cli script into a canvas.

```
let { exec } = require('child_process');
let { Image } = require('canvas');

let image = new Image();

image.onload = function() {
    console.log('Success');
}

image.onerror = function(err) {
    console.error(err);
}

exec("render -id 1 -o", {maxBuffer:1024*10240}, (err, stdout, stderr) => {

    if (err) {
        console.error(err);
        return;
    }


    // Not working
    //image.src = new Buffer(new Uint8Array(stdout));

    // Not working either
    //image.src = Buffer.from(stdout);
});
```

If I in my console run `$ render -id 1 -o > foo.png` it works like a charm, the png is saved as `foo.png`.

Inside the `render -id 1 -o` the final steps of outputting the PNG basically looks a bit like this.

```
process.stdout.write(fs.readFileSync(files[0].tempName));
```

It reads the saved temporary file and outputs it.

Unfortunately I can not *just* return the name of the temp file and then load the png again.

**Update** I suspected the buffersize of the `exec` command caused the issue, so I bumped up the maxBuffer to `1024*10240` which should be something like 10mb. The images should not be larger than 2-3mb. But it didn't help.

Comment: Have you logged `stdout` and `stderr` to check for problems?

Comment: Yes, no errors. I've also tried to run the exact same command in my terminal, and it outputs the PNG just fine.

Comment: What do you mean by "not working"? Is neither `onload` nor `onerror` running? Try adding `encoding: "buffer"` to the `exec` config, otherwise it might be corrupted going through utf8 decoding.